# Why does reversing iterator require index to minus 2 instead of 1?

Tags: python, iterator

When I try to reverse an iterator like how I've done in the example below, I actually get the results printed twice:

```
class TestIterator:

  def __init__(self):
    self.list = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']

  def __iter__(self):
    self.idx = len(self.list) - 1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    try:
      res = self.list[self.idx]
    except IndexError:
      raise StopIteration
    self.idx -= 1
    return res

names = TestIterator()

for name in names:
  print(name)
```

Result:

```
Charlie
Bob
Alice
Charlie
Bob
Alice
```

In the result above, the names are printed twice. I would've expected it to print this way:

```
Charlie
Bob
Alice
```

However, strangely, after poking around for a while, I notice that if I had `self.idx -= 2` instead, it printed only once, but the sequence is still wrong. Example:

```
...
  def __next__(self):
    try:
      res = self.list[self.idx]
    except IndexError:
      raise StopIteration
    self.idx -= 2
    return res
...
```

This prints:

```
Charlie
Alice
Bob
```

I don't understand why I've to minus 2 on the index for the iterator to work correctly. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: Didn't it not work correctly because the result should've been `Charlie Bob Alice`?

Comment: @JoyalMathew That's only when minus self.idx by 2. But I don't understand why I've to minus by 2 for it to work.

Comment: when you used `-2` if printed `Charlie Alice Bob` not `Charlie Bob Alice`. It is just the original list but only every other option.

Comment: `-2` is a valid index. It's the second last object. All negative indices are valid (as well as the positive ones), in the valid range.

Comment: It seems like the sequence is also incorrect, I didn't notice the sequence was wrong too. I would have expected it to print `Charlie Bob Alice`

Comment: It seems you wrote the code with the assumption that negative indexing of a list would cause a IndexError.

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes I did. I thought it would have thrown an error like in java or some other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `self.idx -= 1`, `self.idx` goes through the values `2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4`, with an `IndexError` at `-4`. `-1, -2, -3` are all valid indices in Python.

When you use `self.idx -= 2`, `self.idx` goes through the values `2, 0, -2, -4`. So it only prints three values, but in the wrong order.

Don't use `except IndexError` for this purpose, use `if self.idx < 0` or something.

Also get in the habit of debugging your program with `print` statements. A `print(self.idx)` would have probably revealed what was going on to you.

Comment: Ahhhh.... the negative indexes are valid in Python. Okay, now I can see why this happens. Thank you so much!